# Github actions with Google playstore Api Error: The caller does not have permission

Tags: android, github-actions, google-play-console, google-cloud-console

I'm trying to configure github actions to upload my .aab file to the PlayStore but been stuck on a permission issue which doesn't get fixed event though I've tried all the suggestions online:
I get: [image: Error Image]

I've been looking at the following issue which seems to be identical https://github.com/r0adkll/upload-google-play/issues/11
Was able to create an account and generate the json along with adding permissions. The google cloud api has an owner permission also the API Manager Permission but still I get this error. Any ideas what else I could try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much digging I found out that the problem wasn't with permissions, what was happening was that I had incorrect packageName in the script, after fixing the package name I had incorrect custom track name, so any typo in those fields will show permission error.

After fixing those the upload completed smoothly. Make sure you have correct values in the below fields since the permission error is misleading.

```
...
packageName: com.yourapp
releaseFiles: app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab
track: alpha
status: completed
...
```